# Single meta key with multiple meta value in like comparison

Tags: query-posts, meta-query

How can I search posts with single meta key but possible multiple meta value in like comparison.

Here is my array for query post.

```
Array(
    [post_type] => post
    [posts_per_page] => 3
    [order] => DESC
    [meta_query] => Array(
        [relation] => AND
        [0] => Array(
                [key] => argomento
                [value] => Array(
                        [0] => 2875
                        [1] => 2884
                        [2] => 2877
                        [3] => 2957
                        [4] => 2959
                        [5] => 9628
                        [6] => 3203
                        [7] => 2952
                        [8] => 2947
                        [9] => 2961
                        [10] => 2955
                        [11] => 2950
                        [12] => 2881
                        [13] => 2879
                    )
                [compare] => like
            )
        [1] => Array(
                [key] => geo
                [value] => Array(
                        [0] => 2853
                        [1] => 20914
                        [2] => 2997
                        [3] => 13926
                        [4] => 14037
                        [5] => 2995
                        [6] => 12949
                        [7] => 7622
                    )
                [compare] => LIKE
            )
    )
 )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is that output you pasted?

Comment: This query post fetch post but not like as I want to filter. I need post which contain those id in meta value

Comment: I still do not understand what you are currently doing and what the results are compared to what you want. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem as below. We should compare each meta value instead of passing array in the meta value.

```
Array(
    [post_type] => post
    [posts_per_page] => 3
    [order] => DESC
    [meta_query] => Array(
        [relation] => AND
        [0] => Array(
                [key] => argomento
                [value] => Array([0] => 2875 )
                [compare] => like
            )
        [1] => Array(
                [key] => argomento
                [value] => Array([0] => 2884 )
                [compare] => like
            )
        [2] => Array(
                [key] => argomento
                [value] => Array([0] => 2877 )
                [compare] => like
            )        
        [3] => Array(
                [key] => geo
                [value] => Array([0] => 2853 )
                [compare] => LIKE
            )
    )
 )
```

Thanks